# How to update a row in mysql and insert new record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql table, columns:

```
employee_id (PK), city, start_date(PK), end_date

"0123", "Boston", 01Jan2010, 01Jan2099
```

employee moves to another city, so a new record must be entered to table, and previous `end_date` should be updated.

```
"0123", "Boston", 01Jan2010, 08Sep2013
"0123", "Detroit", 08Sep2013, 01Jan2099
```

What is the most appropriate sql statement to do this?

Comment: Do a query? Not sure what your question is.

Comment: Do you want the old row to be updated automatically?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the update in two queries or wrap it inside a stored procedure.

First, update the current `end_date` of the person.

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     end_date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d%b%Y')
ORDER   BY STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Second, insert new record.

```
INSERT INTO tableName(employee_id, city, start_date, end_date)
VALUES('0123', 'Detroit', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d%b%Y'), '01Jan2099')
```

Here's a stored procedure,

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeRecord
(
    IN empID VARCHAR(15),
    IN newLoc VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE  tableName
    SET     end_date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d%b%Y')
    WHERE   employee_id = empID
    ORDER   BY STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC
    LIMIT   1;

    INSERT INTO tableName(employee_id, city, start_date, end_date)
    VALUES(empID, newLoc, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d%b%Y'), '01Jan2099');
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

USAGE:

```
CALL EmployeeRecord('0123','Detroit')
```

---

As a sidenote, please use `DATE or DATETIME` datatype when storing dates to avoid the use of function on a field which kills the index if there is any.

Comment: What if employee moves to a 3rd city?

Comment: @alwbtc `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC`

Comment: This is a good one. But a trigger most likely won't work in MySql for updating a previous row in the same table...

Comment: Do you know how to get the row with max end_date for a given employee id?

Comment: `SELECT....FROM..WHERE employee_id = ? ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(end_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC LIMIT 1` -- try that, you can either use `start_date` or `end_date`

Comment: you want to insert a record and update the last row right? did you try the answer above?

Comment: is your first statement, a one-line statement? i cant see semi column

Comment: yes. actually it show two queries, the `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

Comment: which part in 1st statement tells it to get the row with max end_date?

Comment: `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC LIMIT 1` but you can either use `start_date` or `end_date`

Comment: @491243: From docs [Restrictions for Stored Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html): A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Comment: @491243: From the question: employee moves to another city, so a new record must be entered to table, and previous end_date should be updated. He talking about same table.

Comment: why do we write `ORDER   BY STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d%b%Y') DESC` instead of `ORDER BY start_date DESC`?

Comment: If you will not convert it to date, it will be sorted in lexigraphical order. Cosider this, 01Dec2012 01Apr2012 01Jan2012 will sorted to 01Apr2012 01Dec2012 01Jan2012 in ascending order.

Comment: but `start_date` is already is a `DATE` object, why do I need to apply `STR_TO_DATE` on it?

Comment: oh, you don't need that. but why are they formatted as `01Jan2099`?